# Is there a way to position where a section is displayed on the page when using an anchor link?

Tags: html, css

I'm using `anchor links` to jump to the different sections on the page.

The problem is, when it jumps, the section moves all the way to the top of the page at the top of the header, so part of the section is hidden.

Is it possible to specify a position for the link to display? I want it to only move the top of the section to the bottom of the header.

I'm very new to coding and have been searching all over the place for a resolution, but I'm not sure if this is even possible or maybe I'm on the wrong path.

I've tried using positioning and margins in my CSS, but that's not working. Here is where I'm at currently.

**HTML:**

```
`<body>
 <header>
   <ul >
    <li><a href="#rambles">Rambles</a></li>
    <li><a href="#recordedMaterial">Recorded Material</a></li>
    <li><a href="#reachOut">Reach Out</a></li>
   </ul>
 </header>`
```

**CSS**:

```
div.section:target {
    position: inherit;
    top: 130px;
}
```

I've tried using position to move the section down below the header, but it's still pushing it to the top and just creating a large space between the section above.

Comment: Can you please provide the code you're using/have tried?  Preferably a web snippet

Comment: @NathanChampion I just updated what I had in the section above. Does that help?